# Angular http Post is not send

Tags: angular, post

I have the following simple post method:

```
createTask(taskName: String, parentTaskId: String) : Observable<any>{
    let headers : HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    let body = {name:taskName,parentTaskId:parentTaskId,version:0};

    console.log("Body: ", headers, JSON.stringify(body), this.BASE_URL + "/save");

    return this.http.post(this.BASE_URL + "/save", body, {headers:headers});
  }
```

When I use it, the console.log is shown like this:

[image]

First thing I'm asking myself: Why are the headers empty? I think there should be content-type?

But the real Problem:
Nothing happens... The Post is not sent, Browser tells me there is no network traffic, no post sent. There is also no error message in the console and when I use exactly the same stuff with Postman the post is sent with 200.

Whats wrong here? I cant see it...

UPDATE:

The post is sent by clicking on a button which activates the following method:

```
addEdit(parentId: String){
    this.tasksService.createTask(this.taskName, parentId);
  }
```

I figured out that THIS works:

```
addEdit(parentId: String){
    this.tasksService.createTask(this.taskName, parentId).subscribe();
  }
```

But I dont know why.

The component with the button is in a seperated module, the service with createTask is outside that folder, but it is called (can see the console log).

So structure iss like:

```
-app
--taskService
--customFormsModule
---tasklist
----taskMenu <== Button here
```

Why is the method with the subscribe working and the other one not? Doesnt make sense to me.

Comment: The reason you need to add a `subscribe()` after the call to `createTask()` is because `createTask` returns an observable. Observables are lazy and only execute and return data if one or more `subscribers` exist. I suggest reading more about this [You can start here](https://luukgruijs.medium.com/understanding-creating-and-subscribing-to-observables-in-angular-426dbf0b04a3)

Answer (score 1):

First, headers are immutable. After you call `set` you need to assign this to the headers variable. And as MikeOne stated, you don't even need to set these headers, because angular automatically adds them for you when you sent something in JSON format. Second, when calling `post` you need to `subscribe` to it, otherwise the observable is not executed (search cold vs hot observable):

So to update your code:

```js
createTask(taskName: string, parentTaskId: string) : Observable<any>{
  let headers : HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
  headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
  
  let body = { name: taskName, parentTaskId, version: 0 };

  return this.http.post(`${this.BASE_URL}save`, body, { headers });
}
```

Which you can call from somewhere else in the following way:

```js
this.createTask('task', 'parent').subscribe((response) => {
  console.log(response); // response body
});
```

---

You can also directly pass in the headers while creating a headers instance:

```js
const headers : HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
});
```

Then you do not need to reassign the variable.

Comment: Good answer. And you don’t actually need that header..